# photorealistic glass bottle render

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, glass, photorealism

how can I achive this kind of material for glass? (photo attached). It looks like noise texture on very high scale, but when I try to set it, the bottle roughness is rising so high it losts the shiny glass material character. Thanks for your advice.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use something like this for the material - use the Noise texture as the basis for a Bump Node, and then use that as the Normal for the glass. I mixed it very heavily with white first (.998) otherwise, it looks too strong and unrealistic. You can also do this by adjusting the strength on the bump node, but I feel this gives more "fine" control. Lastly, use the Facing output of a Layer Weight node, to mix the inner "lighter color" with a more opaque outer "brownish". Don't forget to adjust the Blend Mode settings if you are using EEVEE (right side):

[image: Glass]

Comment: Why use an extra node to mix the _Noise_ with white? The _Bump_ node has a _Strength_ value and a _Distance_ value, I usually use _Strength_, in tutorials they often say use _Distance_ to control the bump... anyway, simply decreasing the _Strength_ to 0.08 with _Distance_ = 1 gives the same result... or _Strength_ = 1 and _Distance_ set to 0.002 (there you even have a correlation to your mix factor: 1 - 0.998 = 0.002) also looks the same.

Comment: Old habit, I guess. Carried over from Substance Designer.